# protobuf-cshap-port unable to resolve dependencies error

Tags: c#, protocol-buffers

So I am using jskeet protobuf-csharp-port(https://github.com/jskeet/protobuf-csharp-port/releases).

I am able to generate c# class from a simple proto which does not contain dependencies to any other class.

But when I try it with a complex Battle class which contains dependencies to MonsterStuff and User class I get an error saying Error: Unable to resolve all dependencies: Battle.proto: MonsterStuff.proto User.proto .

Any ideas on how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

So I solved it by adding '--include_imports' to my command.

The final command will be 'ProtoGen.exe Battle.proto --include_imports -output_directory=%cd%'